# Allow European Format input in ShieldUI NumericTextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting, shieldui

By default ShieldNumericTextBox doesn't allow typing commas and format the entered number automatically to American format (e.g. after typing 10000, it will be 10,000).

I want to change the default format to European format, I found (textTemplate) option at the initiation of the text box, but it didn't work for me for formatting the input, it is useful for adding text next to the number (e.g. KG, EUR...etc).

```
$("#numericTextBox").shieldNumericTextBox({
    textTemplate: "{0:##,##}", // The numbers in my case are percentages with 2 digits after decimal.
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    step: 0.01,
    spinners: true
});
```

This textTemplate will output the same string ("{0:##,##}") when the user finish typing and focus out the textbox.

And also it doesn't format while typing, only when you finish and remove the focus off the input, so it won't help much. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

ShieldUI uses Globalize JS to handle culture-specific formatting of values.

In your case, you should first set the culture to one that separates integer from decimal digits of a number with a comma instead of a period. Then you can set a format for the textTemplate to display it as a numeric value with 2 decimal digits like this:

```
<!-- include the globalize culture -->
<script src="globalize.culture.de.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set a German Globalize culture
    Globalize.culture("de");

    $("#numericTextBox").shieldNumericTextBox({
        textTemplate: "{0:n2}", // display as numeric having 2 decimal fields
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        spinners: true
    });

});
</script>
```

Yet another way to manipulate the text shown is to provide a function like the one below, for the value of textTemplate:

```
textTemplate: function(value) { return "_custom_formatted_string_"; }
```

which will replace all periods with a comma.

Comment: I don't know why but Globalize.culture("de"); didn't work at all, all the culture parameters remained for English format, I did though specifically reverse the (.), (,) in the numberFormat object, it converted the number from American to European, but the field itself doesn't accept commas from the user, I want to user to type in with European format, not convert what we entered. Thanks.

Comment: Update. Setting the culture worked, I included a wrong file before, but now it worked and changed, BUT it didn't do the job fine, first of all commas are still not allowed, you can type in American number and it will be formatted, which is useless, secondly spinners are not working, they swing from 100,00 to 99,99. Any help?